# Mercurial push creates new remote head after a merge

Tags: mercurial, merge

I have two repositories: A (my trunk) and B (a clone of A for building new features).  I have been doing some work in repo B and I wanted to update it with changes from repo A.  I've pulled changes from A into B and gone through the update/merge dance and am ready to push the merged changes up to repo B on my server.  When I attempt to push these changes it tells me that I'll be creating a new remote head.

When I run `hg heads` I only have a single head for repo B locally.  When I check `hg branches` I only have the default branch in repo B, which is what I want.  I've tried updating/merging again but it can't merge an ancestor, so I'm fresh out of ideas.  Should I really just force the push since everything looks clean on my local side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say you've tried `updating / merging again`, but I think you need to `pull / merge` again. If you only have one local head and your `push` will be creating additional remote heads, it's likely that there have been new heads pushed to the remote since you started "the update/merge dance"

Comment: It turned out that I had something not merged in a sub-repo in repo B.  I think I misunderstood which repo was failing in TortoiseHg. After updating and merging the sub-repo and pushing that, I was was able to push repo B's changes.

Comment: Cool, well glad you didn't have to force the push. That's almost always a bad idea, except when you have a new branch. But then when you have a new branch, there's a different option to use that doesn't require the dangerous-looking `--force`.